# xtsible object, looping in quantmod

Tags: r, quantmod, stocks

I would like to loop through a list of stock symbols and print them with `chartSeries`. It would be easier than always changing the argument. Unfortunatly I always get an error, when I want to loop or subset:

```
Error in try.xts(x, error = "chartSeries requires an xtsible object"):
  chartSeries requires an xtsible object
```

Here the code that produces the error:

```
library(quantmod)
stocks <- c("FIS", "AXP", "AVB")
symbols <- (getSymbols(stocks, src='yahoo'))
for (i in symbols){
    chartSeries(i, theme="white",
        TA="addVo();addBBands();addCCI();addSMA(20, col='blue');
        addSMA(5, col='red');addSMA(50, col='black')", subset='last 30 days')     
}
```

or only:

```
  chartSeries(symbols[1], theme="white",
      TA="addVo();addBBands();addCCI();addSMA(20, col='blue');
      addSMA(5, col='red');addSMA(50, col='black')", subset='last 30 days')
```

Answer (score 1):

`symbols` is a character vector. It's not a list of xts objects. Calling `chartSeries` on a character vector causes the error.

```
R> chartSeries("OOPS")
Error in try.xts(x, error = "chartSeries requires an xtsible object") : 
  chartSeries requires an xtsible object
```

One solution is to put all the downloaded data into one environment, then call `chartSeries` on every object in the environment.

```
library(quantmod)
stocks <- c("FIS", "AXP", "AVB")
stockEnv <- new.env()
symbols <- getSymbols(stocks, src='yahoo', env=stockEnv)
for (stock in ls(stockEnv)){
    chartSeries(stockEnv[[stock]], theme="white", name=stock,
        TA="addVo();addBBands();addCCI();addSMA(20, col='blue');
        addSMA(5, col='red');addSMA(50, col='black')", subset='last 30 days')     
}
```